# Caliburn Micro Multi-page Application with Main View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm moving over from WinForms to WPF using MVVM (Specifically Caliburn.Micro), but I'm having a slight problem getting to grips with the entire concept for what I will be using it for.

So the Main window("ShellView") will be segmented into 3 parts, the sidebar, the header bar/context menu and the page controller, and looks like this 
[Application frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Fjf.png)

So the sidebar and the header will be static for everything that's shown, but the main page will change based on which system is being used, for example if the user clicks time, it will open the NS.View.Time.HomeView, then users can navigate through the Time system.

However, I cant seem to get the Shellview sidebar/header buttons to trigger the methods attached to them. I've tried setting the button x:Names to the method names like so

```
<!-- shell View.xaml -->
<Button x:Name = "OpenDashboard"
        Height="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
        Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" 
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ButtonsStackPanel}"
        Cursor="Hand">
</Button>


<!-- Shell View Model.cs -->
public void OpenDashboard()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

I have tested buttons with `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` and setting names of things, which works, but I just can't get the buttons to open different views.

Comment: Are you saying that `OpenDashboard()` is not executed when you click on the button?

Comment: Yes, when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the method?

Comment: Yes, it enters the method, hits the WriteLine, but doesn't do anything

Comment: What do you expect it to do given the current implementation...?

Comment: At the moment, I just expect it to print "Test" to the console

Comment: There is no console attached. If you change the code to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("...")`, you should see the message getting printed to the output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realise that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no console to write to in a WPF application but if you change the code to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test")`, you should see "Test" getting printed to the [output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio when you click on the `Button`.